# Angular.js ReferenceError: $scope is not defined

Tags: angularjs

I have started practicing the basics of Angular.js and was trying some code doing data binding and controllers,  and get the error at following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/yy9wM/

```
$scope.$watch('funding.startingEstimate', computeNeeded);
```

The error I get in browser console is ReferenceError: $scope is not defined. I have read the related questions to this but didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is your app isn't even running. jsfiddle can be tricky to with angular.

Here is what it looks like you were trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/yy9wM/1/

Angular will now bootstrap itself, and be wrapped in the head.

`$scope` is passed into you controller function `CalcController` it is not defined outside of that. It represents the scope of that controller, so any properties defined on that scope are available with in the controller just like {{needed}}.

I'd suggest following a tutorial or revisiting some javascript basics as your code shows little understanding of javascript principals.

Good luck.

Comment: I prefer jsbin to jsfiddle myself.

Comment: @Matthew.Lothian yes I am trying to learn Angular and also new to javscript,thank you for the advice,would revise that and get it done

Comment: @Mike Cheel Thank you for the suggestion,I did also find jsbin more preferable than jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle can be a funky when it comes to loading Angular. You also had $scope.watch defined outside of your controller.

Here is a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/EgTH6OThy8or3rPpi0a7?p=preview